# Getting Network Binding in AWS ECS for a task running in NetworkMode=Host

Tags: amazon-web-services, task, amazon-ecs

Lately we moved are ECS tasks from NetworkMode=Bridge to NetworkMode=Host

We used to have a Java code to retrieve the network binding of a task

The code looked like this:

```
List<NetworkBinding> networkBindings = task.getContainers().get(0).getNetworkBindings();

for (NetworkBinding networkBinding : networkBindings) {
               
 // do something here                
}
```

Now when using a "Host" mode , the list of "networkBindings"  returns empty

Any idea why? Or how to get list now

Thanks